# Controlling the illumination bar on an Xperia U

Tags: android, sony

I would like to control  the "Illumination Bar" of my XperiaU. I would like my application to change the bar's color and intensity. Is this possible?

Comment: I am from Sony Developer Program. This API is not currently public. I will get back to you on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sony has a very good page for developers. I think your question belongs there because it's very specific. 
[Sony Developer](http://developer.sonymobile.com/)

Comment: yes i knows thanks, in menu contacts i see this : "..we recommend you to post any questions on Stack Overflow. We have a team of developers that constantly monitor, contribute and reply to questions regarding our products and tools at Stack Overflow.  So if you have a question, just make sure you tag it with a proper product name or “Xperia”"

Answer (score 0):

We now have an official API to support Illumination.  See here for more details:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/06/20/new-experimental-illumination-bar-api-available/